# Is there a way to clone context in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Let's say our starting context is:

```
import vm from 'node:vm';

const context = {
  foo: {},
};

vm.createContext(context);

vm.runInContext('const foo = {}', context);
```

Is there a way to clone `context` now?, i.e.

```
const a = clone(context);
const b = clone(context);

vm.runInContext('foo.bar = "A"', a);
vm.runInContext('foo.bar = "B"', b);

a.foo.bar === 'A'; // should be true
b.foo.bar === 'B'; // should be true
```